# Get events from iCal

Tags: ios, swift, icalendar, eventkit

I'm trying to get all events from a calendar I subscribed to on my iPhone using EventKit.

I only need events from this specific calendar.

Is it possible to get them? How?

Comment: Here's a guide for Objective-C: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html. Apple hasn't updated the document for Swift yet so you are a bit on your own with the translation.

Answer (score 0):

```
private func getAllEvents() {

    let store = EKEventStore()
    let cal = store.calendarWithIdentifier(yourCalenderIdentifier)
    let oneMonthAgo = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30*24*3600)
    let oneMonthAfter = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: +30*24*3600)

    let predicate = store.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(oneMonthAgo, endDate: oneMonthAfter, calendars: [cal!])

    let events = store.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate)        
}
```